# Vue "Module not found" error after switching image url to and online image

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to dynamically display images, whose names I fetch as strings from a backend. I'm storing all my images in my assets folder, but since there are many images I want to store them online, but keep the same logic for displaying them. The way I did it until now is:

```
  methods: {
    getImage(image) {
      return require(`@/assets/${image}`);
    }
  }
```

and in HTML:

```
<img class="moduleImage" :src="getImage(module.pictureName)" :alt="module.name">
```

Now I try the following in the `getImage(image)` method:

```
getImage(image) {
  return require(`https://onlineImageStorage.com/${image}`);
}
```

and I get a **Module Not Found** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "require" keyword since it's not anymore in **your** sources :

```js
getImage(image) {
  return `https://onlineImageStorage.com/${image}`;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, this solves the issue and the program runs, however now I do not get any image displayed. I believe that is because it looks for an image at the following URL:  http://localhost:8081/https://onlineImageStorage.com/imageName.png

Comment: I'm not an expert with vue.js, but maybe on your html `img` element, use `src` instead of `:src` (remove the two dots) and let me know if it helps

Comment: I fixed it, it was a small typo by me. In the end your advice worked. Thank you very much!